# Integrability implies subset integrability on Jordan regions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

For $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, $B \subseteq A$, and $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$, I know that it is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535459/integrability-on-a-implies-integrability-on-b-subset-a/1535461#1535461) in general that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $A$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $B$.

> My question is regarding the case where where $A$ and $B$ are both Jordan regions (that is, $vol(\partial A) = 0$ and $vol(\partial B) = 0$). In this case, is it true that $f$ being integrable on $A$ implies $f$ being integrable on $B$?

My intuition is telling me that this is indeed true since any counterexample to the general claim seems to involve a non-Jordan region (i.e. $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$). However, I am having trouble coming up with an argument that this is indeed true.

I would appreciate any input/suggestions on tackling this question!