# Showing that $\sup_{g \in C[0,1], \|g\|_\infty = 1} \left|\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right|$ = $\int_0^1 |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$
\newcommand{\d}[1]{\, \mathrm{d} #1}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}
$
Let $f \in C[0,1]$. I am trying to show that:
$$
\sup_{g \in C[0,1], \|g\|_\infty = 1} \left|\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \d{x}\right| = \int_0^1 |f(x)| \d{x}
$$
Here, $\|g\|_\infty := \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |g(x)|$ denotes the sup norm. Note that I'm not certain if this statement is true, but I strongly believe it's true.

---

If we remove the restriction that $g$ is continuous, then this statement is trivial, as we can simply let $g = \sgn \circ f$. Then $f(x)g(x) = |f(x)|$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$. To adhere to the restriction, my idea is to construct a sequence of functions $g_n$ such that as $n \to \infty$, $g_n$ "looks more and more similar" to $\sgn \circ f$. The following is an illustration of my idea:
[image]
As one can see, $g$ behaves similar to $\sgn \circ f$, but when it is $\epsilon$ away from a zero point, it connects to the zero point linearly so to make it continuous. It's also clear that $\|g_n\|_\infty = 1$, unless $f \equiv 0$, in which then it is a trivial case. My idea is to let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$, for each $g_n$, and show that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) \d{x} = \int_0^1 |f(x)| \d{x}
$$
The following is my attempt to formulate a rigorous construction of $g_n$:

> Define:
> $$
> X_0 := \{x \in [0,1] : f(x) = 0\}
> $$
> For each $x \in [0,1]$, define:
> $$
> z_+(x) = \inf((x,1] \cap X_0) \\
> z_-(x) = \sup([0,x) \cap X_0)
> $$
> And finally, for each $\epsilon > 0$, define $h_\epsilon$ as follows:
> $$
> h_\epsilon(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 0, &\text{if $|z_+(x) - z_-(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ or $x = 0$} \\
> \frac{1}{\epsilon}(x - z_-(x)), &\text{if $|z_+(x) - z_-(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ and $x < z_-(x) + \epsilon$ and $x > 0$} \\
> -\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x - z_+(x)), &\text{if $|z_+(x) - z_-(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ and $x > z_+(x) + \epsilon$ and $x > 0$} \\
> -\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x - z_-(x)), &\text{if $|z_+(x) - z_-(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ and $x < z_-(x) + \epsilon$ and $x < 0$} \\
> \frac{1}{\epsilon}(x - z_+(x)), &\text{if $|z_+(x) - z_-(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ and $x > z_+(x) + \epsilon$ and $x < 0$} \\
> 1, &\text{if none of the above and $x > 0$} \\
> -1, &\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> We then denote $g_n = h_{\frac{1}{n}}$.

My main issue here is that, given the complicated structure of $g_n$, I'm not sure how to evaluate $\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) \d{x}$ or bound it properly. I'm also not sure how dense $X_0$ is in $[0,1]$, so I can't seem to guarantee that the measure of the set $Y_\epsilon := \{(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) : x \in X_0\}$ tends to zero, which is probably necessary to show my statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A piecewise linear interpolation of $g(x) = sgn (f(x))$ won't really work, since by the constraints of your problem, the approximations $h_{\epsilon}$ will fail to be differentiable everywhere. The standard approach to these kinds of things is to define the approximation $h_\epsilon$ via mollification: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: for C1-ness, I think you have to smoothing your $g_n$. (in fact it was not differentiable in certain points.) For $
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) d{x} = \int_0^1 |f(x)| d{x}
$ You can deal integral with only the set where $h_{\frac{1}{n}}$ has the value -1 or 1, since $f(x)g_n(x)$ is always positive

Comment: @ClementYung In the original formulation of your problem, the supremum is taken only over $g \in C^1[0,1]$.

Comment: Apologies to both, I meant $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Well, you're not far off from a proof if the zero set $f(x) = 0$ is finite. But that doesn't have to be the case- it's easy to construct ugly continuous functions with countably many discrete zeroes (actually, typical Brownian paths satisfy this property). Then it's more of a pain to work with the $h_\epsilon$ as you've defined it...Using a mollification argument would certainly be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}$Let $\sgn_m(x)$ be $\sgn(x)$ off of $(-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m})$ and $\sgn_m(x)=mx$ in $[-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m}]$. Then:
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_0^1 \sgn_m(f(x))f(x)dx=\int_0^1 \sgn(f(x))f(x)dx=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx
$$

Comment: Your definition of $\mathrm{sgn}_m$ is not clear. Please clarify by giving a precise definition of it.

Comment: He defines it pretty clearly in the first sentence. Which part is unclear?

Comment: Why do you feel it is imprecise? Maybe this will help you.  For $x\in[-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m}], sgn_m(x)=mx$. For $x>\frac{1}{m}, sgn_m(x)=1$ and for $x<-\frac{1}{m}, sgn_m(x)=-1$

Comment: It is a continuous approximation to the sign function. A small sketch will convince you.

Comment: I see, I was not sure what he meant by "off of $(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m})$". Thanks for the clarification everyone.

Comment: Can you give me a rigorous idea/start of a proof why the following is true?
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_0^1 \mathrm{sgn}_m(f(x))f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \mathrm{sgn}(f(x))f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: The intergrands only differ where $|f(x)|<\frac{1}{m}$ i.e. the integands only differ where the integrands are small so the difference of the integrands is bounded by $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Good point. Thanks!

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh sorry, allow me to first clarify. How are we able to guarantee that $\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))f(x)$ is integrable on the domain where $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{m}$, since [integrable on $[0,1]$ does not imple integrable on any subsets of $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535549/does-integrability-on-set-implies-integrability-on-opportune-subset)?

Comment: You integrate over all of $[0,1]$. However, it is only non zero where $|f(x)|<\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: In other words, you're defining a function $g$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ if $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{m}$ and $0$ otherwise. How can we guarantee that this funciton is Riemann integrable?

Comment: It was a difference of two riemann intergrable functions. The previously mentioned integrands.

Comment: Right, not sure why I missed that out. Thanks!